# Average incorrect by decimal points in my Report Card program

Tags: java

When I am calculating my average for my Report Card program, it is off by a few decimal numbers. When I add 98 + 100 I'm supposed to get 99 as the average. Instead, I am getting 98.5. I'm not sure if it is a problem with my count variable. Why is this and how can I fix it? My code is below.

Here is the output I am getting

```
What is your name? AG
What course would you like to calculate the average of? Algebra 2

Enter grade #1 (enter -1 to exit): 98
Enter grade #2 (enter -1 to exit): 100
Enter grade #3 (enter -1 to exit): -1
AG, your average in Algebra 2 is 98.5%. That's an A!
Keep up the hark work!

Would you like to check another course? (y/n) n

Good bye!
```

And here is the output I want

```
What is your name? AG
What course would you like to calculate the average of? Algebra 2

Enter grade #1 (enter -1 to exit): 98
Enter grade #2 (enter -1 to exit): 100
Enter grade #3 (enter -1 to exit): -1
AG, your average in Algebra 2 is 99%. That's an A!
Keep up the hark work!

Would you like to check another course? (y/n) n

Good bye!
```

```
public class MyProgram extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public void run()
    {
        // Start here!
        String name = readLine("What is your name? ");
        String course = readLine("What course would you like to calculate the average of? ");
        System.out.println("");
        
        int gradenum = 1;
        int count = 0;
        double average = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        double newcount = 0;
        
        while(true)
        {
            int grade = readInt("Enter grade #" + gradenum++ + " (enter -1 to exit): ");
            
            count++;
            sum += grade;
            newcount = count - 1;
            average = sum/newcount;
            
            if(grade == -1)
            {
                gradenum = 1;
            }
            
            if(grade == -1)
            {
                if(average >= 90 && average <= 100)
                {
                    System.out.print(name);
                    System.out.print(", your average in ");
                    System.out.print(course);
                    System.out.print(" is ");
                    System.out.print(average);
                    System.out.println("%. That's an A!");
                    System.out.println("Keep up the hark work!");
                    System.out.println("");
                }
        
                if(average < 90 && average >= 80)
                {
                    System.out.print(name);
                    System.out.print(", your average in ");
                    System.out.print(course);
                    System.out.print(" is ");
                    System.out.print(average);
                    System.out.println("%. That's a B!");
                    System.out.println("You're doing a fine job!");
                    System.out.println("");
                }
        
                if(average < 80 && average >= 70)
                {
                    System.out.print(name);
                    System.out.print(", your average in ");
                    System.out.print(course);
                    System.out.print(" is ");
                    System.out.print(average);
                    System.out.println("%. That's a C!");
                    System.out.println("You're passing the class.");
                    System.out.println("");
                }
        
                if(average < 70 && average >= 60)
                {
                    System.out.print(name);
                    System.out.print(", your average in ");
                    System.out.print(course);
                    System.out.print(" is ");
                    System.out.print(average);
                    System.out.println("%. That's a D.");
                    System.out.println("You're close to passing. You can do it!");
                    System.out.println("");
                }
        
                if(average <= 60)
                {
                    System.out.print(name);
                    System.out.print(", your average in ");
                    System.out.print(course);
                    System.out.print(" is ");
                    System.out.print(average);
                    System.out.println("%. That's an F.");
                    System.out.println("I think you need to ask your teacher for help.");
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }
             while(grade == -1)
            {
                String y = "y";
                String n = "n";
                String repeat = readLine("Would you like to check another course? (y/n) ");
                
                if(repeat.equals(n))
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println("Good bye!");
                }
                
                if(repeat.equals(n))
                {
                    return;
                    //break;
                }
                
                
                
                }

            }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I don't think it'll fix it but one suggestion I have is make your grade sum an `int` if you're using `readInt` to store the input into `grade` which is an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't update your count, sum, and average until AFTER you've determined that the number was NOT a -1:

```
if(grade == -1)
{
    gradenum = 1;
}
else
{
    count++;
    sum += grade;
    newcount = count - 1;
    average = sum/newcount;
}
```

Also, you have a lot of repeated code in your `if` blocks.  You can reduce your code by quite a bit by outputting the common parts at the top.  The conditional statements can also be reduced:

```
System.out.print(name);
System.out.print(", your average in ");
System.out.print(course);
System.out.print(" is ");
System.out.print(average);

if (average >= 90)
{
    System.out.println("%. That's an A!");
    System.out.println("Keep up the hark work!");
}
else if (average >= 80)
{
    System.out.println("%. That's a B!");
    System.out.println("You're doing a fine job!");
}
else if (average >= 70)
{
    System.out.println("%. That's a C!");
    System.out.println("You're passing the class.");
}
else if (average >= 60)
{
    System.out.println("%. That's a D.");
    System.out.println("You're close to passing. You can do it!");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("%. That's an F.");
    System.out.println("I think you need to ask your teacher for help.");
}
System.out.println("");
```